# Jquery add elements based on a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

i'm trying to add(and remove but i'll try that when this will work) a number of selects based on the value of a main select when said select changes.

I have a

```
Number of Selects
    <select id="selectNumber">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
```

And a single

```
Select 1 Options
    <select id="selectN1">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    </select>
```

Now, changing the #selectNumber should add more SelectN* based on his value and this is what should do that:

```
$("#selectNumber").on("change", function(){
    var n = $("#selectNumber").val();
    for (i=2;i<=n;i++){
        var c = i-1;
        $("#selectN"+c).after("<br />Select "+i+" options <select id='selectN"+i+"'><option>option1</option><option>option2</option></select>");
    }
}
);
```

This is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xPZUn/14/

On my page it runs ok but it only adds a second select item(even if 3 ore more are selected in the main select) i guess that's cause the for loop can't select the dynamically created elements to append more.
On the fiddle it doesn't even add a second select.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your code has several syntax errors with missing closing brackets and braces. Once those are fixed, it works, however if you select `3`, and then `1` you end up with 4 select  elements, so you need to clear the previously appended. Try this:

```
$("#selectNumber").on("change", function () {
    $('.additional-select').remove(); // remove existing
    for (i = 1; i < +$("#selectNumber").val(); i++) {
        $("#selectN" + i).after('<div class="additional-select">Select ' + (i + 1) + ' options <select id="selectN' + (i + 1) + '"><option>option1</option><option>option2</option></select>');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xPZUn/24/)

Note that the `i + 1` is wrapped in brackets to ensure the result is appended, not the value of `i` and `1` appended individually as was previously happening.

Comment: Yep i wrote it quite in a hurry and made some mistakes, will edit the updated fiddle in the op.

Comment: Thanks for the added remove part. Apart from the remove part it was like this in my page but it still didn't work; i'll try looking into it a bit further asap.
Thanks for the reply